# Какой частью речи является «даже»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, части-речи

*Даже при нарушении личных неимущественных прав(,) применяются меры имущественного характера*.

Какой частью речи является "даже" в этом предложении? Нужна ли запятая перед "применяются"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Даже при нарушении личных неимущественных прав применяются меры имущественного характера.*

[**Даже**](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Dazhe-2759.html) в этом предложении является усилительной **частицей**.
Она употребляется для выделения и усиления слова или словосочетания, к которому относится (ставится обычно перед выделяемыми словами).

Запятая не нужна (частицу можно изъять без потери смысла).
Если это *полное* предложение, то в самом конце необходима точка (если же это неполная цитата, то нужно поставить многоточие).

**Даже** при гораздо более низких мировых ценах на нефть и её производные крестьяне каждый раз перед началом весеннего сева в один голос кричат о нехватке денег на горючее и сговоре нефтяных компаний. [Игорь Пылаев. Война срывает посевную // «Еженедельный журнал», 2003.04.08]

**Даже** при сближении Гаспры с Землёй эти небесные тела разделяют не десятки тысяч, а миллионы километров. [Е. Левитан. Обычные и необычные астероиды // «Наука и жизнь», 2008]

***Даже** при возмещении морального вреда восстановительное воздействие проявляется в денежном выражении* (из статьи "Судебная защита").

Answer (score 0):

‟ Даже ” здесь усилительная частица. В этом предложении сочетание слов ‟ даже при нарушении личных неимущественных прав ” является условным обстоятельственным оборотом. Ничего отчетливого в справочниках про это не написано, так что можете писать как хотите ( ставить запятую или не ставить ). Если кто-то вас поправит, то просто скажите этому человеку, что он ничего не смыслит в факультативной пунктуации.